# How to change image path in .oft file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, templates

I have several oft files with pictures from `https://aaa.com/images/`. After domain change I have `https://bbb.com/images/` situation. I should just change url for pictures I guess but I can't find how to do it.

Outlook offers two options:

1. from file
2. from online sources (onedrive and bing)

I would like to insert URL `https://bbb.com/images/image.png`, how to do that?

EDIT:
If I should ask this somewhere else, please direct me.

Comment: Are you asking how to edit the Outlook template? If so, what does your situation with the image URL have to do with your question?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I asked what is written, If you think that I tagged question wrongly, feel free to correct it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You ask how to change the URL ("I should...change url...but I can't find how to do it"), but it seems like the problem you're actually facing is that you don't know how to *edit the template.* But since you don't actually say that, I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: From the description, this issue seems to be mostly related with editing template. You can directly edit the template and change the URL for image.  https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4643-outlook-edit-template.html